# Get the nested controls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a Parent User Control in which i have registered a Child UserControl.
I want to access the controls present in the child usercontrol in my aspx page that I have inherited from a Master page.

Below is my code:

```
//Parent UserControl
    public partial class WebUserControlParent : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public WebUserControlChild checkbox
        {
            get
            {
                return this.checkbox;
            }
        }
        public WebUserControlChild label
        {
            set
            {
                this.label = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return this.label;
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
//Child User Control : 
     public partial class WebUserControlChild : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public bool Checked
        {
            set
            {
                this.checkboxchild.Checked = value;
            }
        }
        public string Text
        {
            set
            {
                this.labelchild.Text = "YooHoo!";
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
//My Aspx Page:
     public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.PageControl.checkbox.Checked = true;
            this.PageControl.label.Text = "YoooHooo!";
        }
    }
//My Parent usercontrol .ascx stuff
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControlParent.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="WebApplication2.WebUserControlParent" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControlChild.ascx" TagName="Child" TagPrefix="cc" %>

//My Child Usercontrol Stuff
        <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControlChild.ascx.cs"
        Inherits="WebApplication2.WebUserControlChild" %>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxchild" runat="server" Checked="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="labelchild" runat="server"></asp:Label>

//My ASPX Page Stuff
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

    <%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControlParent.ascx" TagName="Control" TagPrefix="cc" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <cc:Control ID="PageControl" runat="server" />
    </asp:Content>
```

When i do this, my code says thread excited with some code... Can anybody suggest me what i`m doing wrong and what should be the solution for this.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking messages in your output-window? (So not a compiler error or runtime error?)

In that case: that is normal behavior. Every time a client does a request for a page, a thread is started and when the page is rendered and sent back to the client, that thread will terminate an producte this message. Nothing to worry about.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs4c1wda.aspx

Answer (score 0):

your parent control code behind will be like this

```
//Parent UserControl
public partial class WebUserControlParent : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public WebUserControlChild mChildControl
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ctrlChild;
        }
        set{
           this.ctrlChild = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

child control codebehind will be

```
 public partial class WebUserControlChild : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public bool Checked
    {
        set
        {
            this.checkboxchild.Checked = value;
        }
        get{
            return this.checkboxchild.Checked;
        }

    }
    public string Text
    {
        set
        {
            this.labelchild.Text = value;
        }
        get{
            return this.labelchild.Text;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

aspx page codebehind will be

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ctrlPageControl.mChildControl.Checked = true;
        this.ctrlPageControl.mChildControl.Text = "YoooHooo!";
    }
}
```

//My Parent usercontrol .ascx stuff

```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"   CodeBehind="WebUserControlParent.ascx.cs"
  Inherits="WebApplication2.WebUserControlParent" %>
  <%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControlChild.ascx" TagName="Child" TagPrefix="cc" %>
  <cc:Control ID="ctrlChild" runat="server" />
```

//My Child Usercontrol Stuff

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControlChild.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="WebApplication2.WebUserControlChild" %>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxchild" runat="server" Checked="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="labelchild" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

//My ASPX Page Stuff

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

  <%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControlParent.ascx" TagName="Control" TagPrefix="cc" %>
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <cc:Control ID="ctrlPageControl" runat="server" />
  </asp:Content>
```